# Configuration space of n particles, considering collisions.

Tags: dynamical-systems, physics

What would be the configuration space of $n$ particles (each particle position being in $\mathbb{R}^3$), if one insists that it should be such that no two particles can be at the same position?

For two ($n=2$) particles each with position in $\mathbb{R}^1$, I suppose this would be the plane with the line $y=x$ removed from it. This immediately tells us that if the system starts in one region of the space, then it cannot cross $y=x$ to the other. This makes sense since a particle cannot jump over the other, but is special to this case.

Comment: What do you mean by 'what would be the configuration space...'? Do you want to know properties of these spaces? In general, we know a lot about their homotopy groups and homology/cohomology. The configuration space of $n$ labelled particles in a space $X$ is defined to be $Conf(X,n) = X^n \setminus \Delta$ where $\Delta$ is the 'fat diagonal' $\Delta = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in X^n \mid \exists i\neq j, \: x_i = x_j\}$. For unlabelled particles, one should mod out by the natural $S_n$ action given by permuting coordinates.

Comment: Yes, and the information you give is an answer. Could you also suggest a reference to read about this topic, while still relating it to applications in physics and not only delving in the mathematical side?

Comment: I'm afraid I've only really been exposed to configuration spaces in relation to algebraic topology e.g. braid groups (and a little bit of robotics in connection with motion planning). For the algebraic topology side of things I would recommend Hansen's *Braids and Coverings* which is aimed at grad students, or Birman's *Braids, Links and Mapping Class Groups* for a more detailed, but harder to read introduction. These may not be suitable for someone without the relevant background in algebraic topology however.